# Trying to Find Maximum Value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to find a maximum number of a string. First I try to turn it into an Integer field first, but keep getting error message for example:
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '3,029' to data type int.

I tried to replace the possible single quotation marks into a blank char like below:

```
SELECT TOP 100 (CAST(REPLACE(a.PortNumber,'''','') AS INT)) FROM dbo.Account a
WHERE nwp_AccountType = 121710000
ORDER BY (CAST(REPLACE(a.PortNumber,'''','') AS INT)) DESC
```

But still getting the same error message again.

Any idea?

Comment: Can't you change the column type to integer? This is a really bad approach!

Comment: are you sure it's not the comma that's causing the problem?  replace it instead of the '  Numbers typically don't STORE the comma, they display it on a format mask  unless , is a decimal notation for your region.

Comment: Thanks! I replaced the comma and it's working!

Comment: As stb and xQbert have already stated, the better approach is to define the column as integer instead of nvarchar.

Comment: If this is a number field you are asking for problems later by not chaining it to a number type (int, for example). For example, -- wait until you're asked to do math with the field, or aggregate functions.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in your `REPLACE` statement

```
(CAST(REPLACE(a.PortNumber,',','') AS INT))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the comma, I added another replace for the comma to an empty string and it works.